# Vuetify stepper simple component wrapper v-on="$listeners" error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a component wrapper for the Vuetify Stepper component.
My goal is to simply create a wrapper so that I can apply some CSS overrides.

So I want to pass down all the `$attrs`, `$listeners`, `$slots`.

I don't want to change any behavior/js.

Here is my `my-stepper.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <v-stepper v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
    <slot></slot>
  </v-stepper>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "my-stepper",
  inheritAttrs: false,
};
</script>
```

```css
<style lang="scss">
// Fix issue with the vertical stepper component in vuetify
.v-stepper.v-stepper--vertical .v-stepper__content.active > .v-stepper__wrapper {
  height: auto !important; // allow the active step to have automatic height (if child change)
  padding: 4px; // fix an overflow issue
}
</style>
```

I use this component like:

```
<my-stepper vertical v-model="currentStepNumber" elevation="0">...</my-stepper>
```

But now, when I use `my-stepper` I got the following error in Chrome:

`[Vuetify] [BREAKING] '@input' has been removed, use '@change' instead. For more information, see the upgrade guide https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0#user-content-upgrade-guide`.

This error disappears when I remove the `v-on="$listeners"` but I need it to pass down the events. Don't I?

Any help or proposal for a simple component wrapper is appreciated.

Comment: You didn't show how `my-stepper` is being used. Maybe you added `@input` on it and so that's being passed down to `v-stepper` via `$listeners`?

Comment: @doesnotmatter I've updated the question to add how I use `my-stepper`. I have a `v-model` on it.

Comment: that explains why you're getting the `@input` event. `v-model` is just a syntactic sugar for `@input` + `:value`. Docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a valid soution to my issue.
In my wrapper component, in the script section I needed to add a `model` object to specify the `event` name (from default being `input` to `change`):

```js
export default {
  name: "vertical-stepper",
  inheritAttrs: false,
  model: {
    prop: "value",
    event: "change",
  },
};
</script>
```

This refers to [Customizing the Component v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` is just a syntactic sugar for `@input` + `:value`.

From the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

```html
<input v-model="searchText">
```

does the same thing as:

```html
<custom-input
  v-bind:value="searchText"
  v-on:input="searchText = $event"
></custom-input>
```

Comment: Changing `v-model="currentStepNumber` to `:value="currentStepNumber" @change="currentStepNumber = $event"` solved my issue indeed. But that's weird that `v-stepper` accept `v-model` but not `@input` via a `v-on="$listeners"`..

Comment: I can use `v-model` on `v-stepper` so I would love to use it on `my-stepper` too.

Comment: If you are using Vuetify 2 then there's nothing you can do. It already says it's a **BREAKING** change and refers you to the upgrade guide. I'm not sure why you say it's working because it's clearly not in Vuetify v2 codebase.

Comment: I found a solution now. Thanks for helping me out pointing at the `v-model` syntactic sugar.